# Partial function in scala

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I see the following code in several places depicting the use of partial functions in Scala.

```
val divide: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case d: Int if d != 0 => 42 / d
}
```

Here, divide is a variable whose type of is PartialFunction[Int,Int] which is a trait. I am confused about the RHS part. Since the type of the variable "divide" is: PartialFunction[Int,Int] , it needs to be instantiated by using a "new" keyword. I am not sure about the kind of syntax this is. Plus how isdefined() function automatically defined above ? ( isDefined() seems available; but it is there hidden).

Can someone please help.

Comment: Objects do not have to be instanciated using `new`, the compiler can create objects directly  for literals (`0`,`"Hello"`) or indeed when it creates a function (which is just an instance of a `Function` class). In this case it creates an instance of `PartialFunction` using that syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand-side is a function literal in cases.

It's a literal, just like an `Int`, `Char`, `String` don't have a `new` keyword before the literal.

A function in cases has the syntax

```
{
  case ... => ...
  (optionally more cases)
}
```

The expected type must be fully known. If a `PartialFunction` is expected, it's taken as a PartialFunction. Otherwise, it's taken as a `Function1`

For the `PartialFunction` variation, it's `isDefinedAt` is defined by the patterns of the cases.

Comment: I don't think it has to be a `Function1` - afaik it can also expand to a function with multiple parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I try to do the following... val x = { case _ => "Nothing" }  ad I am getting the error... "Missing parameter type for the expanded function.."

Comment: Yes, I forgot, you can only use function literals if the expected type if fully known. `val x: Any => String = { case _ => "Nothing" }` will work

Comment: I have one more question.. When I write, val x = Int=>Int = { case x => 2*x } OR val x: Int=>Int = 2*_ . Both work.  But when I do: val y: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = { case x => 2 * x } OR val y: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = 2*_ only the first case works. The second case errors out. Could you please help.
though the input type is implicit via the declaration of PartialFunction[Int,Int].

Comment: `2 * _` is only ever parsed as a `Function` literal, never as a `PartialFunction` literal. Only literals in cases are parsed as PartialFunction literals (if one is expected and the argument type is fully known).